# How to create a database in docker mysql/mysql-server image and connect it through java

Tags: java, mysql, docker

I have pulled the image mysql/mysql-server from the docker hub. Now I wanted to create a table with name and email columns and connect to this mysql db from java

Can I connect to this db using the below statement ?

Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxx:xxxxx/dbname","uname","pwd");

Comment: have you tried? i don't think a yes/no question is a good one for this site tbh

Comment: i am not having db  uname and pwd so my question is how to create

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker inspect <container_name>` to check details of a docker container. In the output you can find IP address of the container under "NetworkSettings" section.

After getting the IP address of the container, you can treat it just like a remote server and connect to it using normal mysql-client or in Java code using JDBC.

Comment: How can i  have dbname, uname and pwd to access that db in eclipse

Comment: Do i need to grant permission of that db for my machine ip to access ???

Comment: It depends on how the container is configured. Normally they have some predefined user/pass which you can use to connect and change password, create db, ...

Comment: I have typed docker exec -ti <container name> /bin/bash and entered into the container now how can i create a db so that i can access it from eclipse

Comment: I think the best thing is using the documentation for the image you are using, which is available at https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/.

Comment: For example to set a password you can start the container via `docker run --name my-container-name -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql/mysql-server:tag`, or to have a mysql client inside your running container you can run `docker exec -it my-container-name mysql -uroot -p`

Answer (score 0):

You should do this. Did you run the container before? From where you want to connect to the DB (a container?), try a "telnet  "

If the connection is accepted, you are OK.

Comment: I have started the container using below command   docker run --name <name of my container> -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<my pwd > -d mysql:mysql-server  Now i wanted to create a table so that i can access from eclipse in same machine

Comment: Connect to your DB container with: "docker exec -ti <container name> /bin/bash" and create what you need. Or use the phpmyadmin or adminer image to do this with a GUI.

Comment: I have typed the above command and it opened  this sh-4.2#   now what i need to do to create a db and create tables in that db

Answer (score 0):

You should create your connection string with the db service name (or container name)

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<mysqlcontainername>/dbname","uname","pwd");
```

Note that your java application container and the mysql container must be in the same docker network.

I suggest to create a complete connection string injected from an environment variable (this is a really sweet procedure for Sysadmins):

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://username:password@<mysqlcontainername>/dbname");
```